# Which Two-Sample Test for Non-Independent Data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, independence, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, macroeconomics

I am interested in determining whether there are statistically significant differences in the mean twelve-month (percentage) changes of various financial variables, conditioned on the state of the world in a given month. As a specific example, I would like to know whether the mean next-twelve-month change in the US unemployment rate following months in which the US 10-Year Treasury rate was below a certain threshold is significantly different from the corresponding change following months in which the US 10-Year Treasury rate was above the same threshold.

Concretely, I have a single time series of monthly data, where the values are the cumulative changes in the unemployment rate over the next twelve months. Because I have overlapping observations the data are highly autocorrelated. I then split this data into two samples based on whether the US Treasury rate was above or below a threshold at the end of the previous month. Finally, I calculate the means of the two samples.

I'm now trying to determine the best test to use in order to determine whether the means of the two samples differ significantly from each other. I have considered the two-sample t-test and the Mann-Whitney test, but as far as I can tell they both assume that the values in sample 1 are independent form the values in sample 2. In my case this isn't applicable, since for example January 1960 could be in sample 1 and February 1960 could be in sample 2, and they definitely aren't independent because of the overlapping way in which they are calculated.

Is there a test which would be directly appropriate for my situation, or should I reconsider my whole approach to the question?